# Spacing in Multicols and Array

Tags: enumerate, multicol, arrays

The following shows my work in LaTeX recently:
[image]

I made this with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.05in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
Solve each system of equations algebraically.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=12pt
        \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} 2x + 3y & = & 3 \\ 12x - 15y & = & -4 \end{array} \right.$
        \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} y & = & 6-x \\ x & = & \dfrac{9}{2} + y \end{array} \right.$
        \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} x & = & 2y-8 \\ 2x-y & = & 7 \end{array} \right.$
        \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} \dfrac{3}{5}x - \dfrac{1}{6}y & = & 1 \\ \dfrac{1}{5}x + \dfrac{5}{6}y & = & 11 \end{array} \right.$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, the spacing of the fractions in item (d) looks awkward. Furthermore, (b) is not aligned with (d). Is there any workaround with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding extra \\  or [9pt] after the \\
in the array of item d:

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.05in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
Solve each system of equations algebraically.
 \begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate} \itemsep=12pt
    \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} 2x + 3y & = & 3 \\ 12x - 15y & = & -4 \end{array} \right.$
    \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} y & = & 6-x \\ x & = & \dfrac{9}{2} + y \end{array} \right.$
    \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} x & = & 2y-8 \\ 2x-y & = & 7 \end{array} \right.$
    \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} \dfrac{3}{5}x - \dfrac{1}{6}y & = & 1 \\[9pt] %% added 9pt 
  \dfrac{1}{5}x + \dfrac{5}{6}y & = & 11 \end{array} \right.$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Renewing `\arraystretch` will solve both issues at once. It changes the height of rows in your array. So choosing an appropriate value will result in better spacing for the fractions in your system. Simultaneously it makes all your rows the same height, so the items in the left column are now the same size as the items in the right column which will align (a) with (c) and (b) with (d) as wanted.

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.05in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Solve each system of equations algebraically.
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate} \itemsep=12pt
                \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} 2x + 3y & = & 3 \\ 12x - 15y & = & -4 \end{array} \right.$
                \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} y & = & 6-x \\ x & = & \dfrac{9}{2} + y \end{array} \right.$
                \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} x & = & 2y-8 \\ 2x-y & = & 7 \end{array} \right.$
                \item $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} \dfrac{3}{5}x - \dfrac{1}{6}y & = & 1 \\ \dfrac{1}{5}x + \dfrac{5}{6}y & = & 11 \end{array} \right.$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also consider using the `exam` class:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\alph{choice}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{(\thechoice)}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
        \question Solve each system of equations algebraically.
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices} 
            \choice $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} 2x + 3y & = & 3 \\ 12x - 15y & = & -4 \end{array} \right.$
            \choice $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} y & = & 6-x \\ x & = & \dfrac{9}{2} + y \end{array} \right.$
            \choice $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} x & = & 2y-8 \\ 2x-y & = & 7 \end{array} \right.$
            \choice $\left\{ \begin{array} {rcl} \dfrac{3}{5}x - \dfrac{1}{6}y & = & 1 \\ \dfrac{1}{5}x + \dfrac{5}{6}y & = & 11 \end{array} \right.$
        \end{choices}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `tabular` is more feasible here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.05in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcases{mycases}{\quad}{%
    \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}       
    \item you could also do:

    %\begin{center} % optional
        \begin{tabular}{%
                l
                >{$}p{7.82cm}<{$} % or optional just ">{$}l<{$}"
                l
                >{$}l<{$}
                }
            (a) & 
            \begin{mycases}
            2x + 3y &= 3 \\ 12x - 15y &=  -4
            \end{mycases} & 
            (b) &
             \begin{mycases}
                y & = 6-x \\ x & = \dfrac{9}{2} + y
             \end{mycases} \\\addlinespace
            (c) & 
            \begin{mycases}
                x &= 2y-8 \\ 2x-y &= 7
            \end{mycases} & 
            (d) &
            \begin{mycases}
                \dfrac{3}{5}x - \dfrac{1}{6}y &= 1 \\ \dfrac{1}{5}x + \dfrac{5}{6}y &= 11
            \end{mycases}            
        \end{tabular}
    %\end{center} % optional
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]